# Puppet: add file for all users?

Tags: puppet

If I want to add a file to a specific directory with Puppet I can use:

```
file { "/folder/file_name":
    ensure => present,
    source => [puppet///file_name],
}
```

Is there a way I can add a file to each user's home directory?

Something like:

```
file { "/home/$USER/filename":
    ensure => present,
    source => [puppet///filename],
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to decide whether the users on that server should be known or unknown at the time of configuration application. Which will it be?

Comment: @MattSchuchard do you mean whether or not I know what the user name will be? If so I won't know the name ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as this is *nix, then you can add a custom fact to assemble the home directories on a system. I suggest naming it `homedirs.rb` when you create it inside of the module's `lib/facter/` directory.

```
# collect home directories
Facter.add(:homedirs) do
  setcode do
    # grab home directories on system and convert into array
    `ls /home`.split("\n")
  end
end
```

If you want this for all non-Windows you can add a:

```
unless Facter.value(:kernel) == 'Windows'
```

around the code block, or keep it to just Linux with:

```
confine kernel: linux
```

above the `setcode`.

Then, you can use a lambda to iterate through this fact array and apply the file resource.

```
# iterate through homedirs in fact array
$facts['homedirs'].each |$homedir| {
  # copy file to home directory
  file { "/home/$homedir/filename":
    ensure => file,
    source => puppet:///filename,
  }
}
```

I also fixed up a few issues with your `file` resource there.

Some helpful doc links in case any of this is confusing:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#file
https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#adding-custom-facts-to-facter
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/function.html#each